# Set column names when stacking pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

When stacking a pandas `DataFrame`, a `Series` is returned. Normally after I stack a `DataFrame`, I convert it back into a `DataFrame`. However, the default names coming from the stacked data make renaming the columns a bit hacky. What I'm looking for is an easier/built-in way to give columns sensible names after stacking.

E.g., for the following `DataFrame`:

```
In [64]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 
    ...:                    'date':['2015-09-31']*3, 
    ...:                    'value':[100, 95, 42], 
    ...:                    'value2':[200, 57, 27]}).set_index(['id','date'])

In [65]: df
Out[65]: 
               value  value2
id date                     
1  2015-09-31    100     200
2  2015-09-31     95      57
3  2015-09-31     42      27
```

I stack and convert it back to a `DataFrame` like so:

```
In [68]: df.stack().reset_index()
Out[68]: 
   id        date level_2    0
0   1  2015-09-31   value  100
1   1  2015-09-31  value2  200
2   2  2015-09-31   value   95
3   2  2015-09-31  value2   57
4   3  2015-09-31   value   42
5   3  2015-09-31  value2   27
```

So in order to name these columns appropriately I would need to do something like this:

```
In [72]: stacked = df.stack()

In [73]: stacked
Out[73]: 
id  date              
1   2015-09-31  value     100
                value2    200
2   2015-09-31  value      95
                value2     57
3   2015-09-31  value      42
                value2     27
dtype: int64

In [74]: stacked.index.set_names('var_name', level=len(stacked.index.names)-1, inplace=True)

In [88]: stacked.reset_index().rename(columns={0:'value'})
Out[88]: 
   id        date var_name  value
0   1  2015-09-31    value    100
1   1  2015-09-31   value2    200
2   2  2015-09-31    value     95
3   2  2015-09-31   value2     57
4   3  2015-09-31    value     42
5   3  2015-09-31   value2     27
```

Ideally, the solution would look something like this:

```
df.stack(new_index_name='var_name', new_col_name='value')
```

But looking at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it doesn't look like `stack` takes any such arguments. Is there an easier/built-in way in pandas to deal with this workflow?

Comment: renaming is the worst part of `stack`. great otherwise!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) is often useful for converting DataFrames from "wide" to "long" format. You could use `pd.melt` here if you convert the `id` and `date` index levels to  columns first:

```
In [56]: pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['id', 'date'], value_vars=['value', 'value2'], var_name='var_name', value_name='value')
Out[56]: 
   id        date var_name  value
0   1  2015-09-31    value    100
1   2  2015-09-31    value     95
2   3  2015-09-31    value     42
3   1  2015-09-31   value2    200
4   2  2015-09-31   value2     57
5   3  2015-09-31   value2     27
```

Comment: +1 but a little bit of elaboration would be ideal. Also maybe capital start the column names as I got confused with so many `value`s about.

Answer (score 29):

So here's one way that you may find a bit cleaner, using the fact that `columns` and `Series` can also carry names.

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]: 
               value  value2
id date                     
1  2015-09-31    100     200
2  2015-09-31     95      57
3  2015-09-31     42      27

In [46]: df.columns.name = 'var_name'

In [47]: s = df.stack()

In [48]: s.name = 'value'

In [49]: s.reset_index()
Out[49]: 
   id        date var_name  value
0   1  2015-09-31    value    100
1   1  2015-09-31   value2    200
2   2  2015-09-31    value     95
3   2  2015-09-31   value2     57
4   3  2015-09-31    value     42
5   3  2015-09-31   value2     27
```

Answer (score 12):

A pipe-ing friendly alternative to chrisb's answer:

```
df.stack().rename_axis(['id', 'date', 'var_name']).rename('value').reset_index()
```

And if explicit is better than implicit:

```
(
    df
    .stack()
    .rename_axis(index={'id': 'id', 'date': 'date', None: 'var_name'})
    .rename('value')
    .reset_index()
)
```

When using the dict mapper, you can skip the names which should stay the same:

```
df.stack().rename_axis(index={None: 'var_name'}).rename('value').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not something like this?
Sometimes `melt` is great,
but sometimes you want to keep your index,
and/or you want to have an index on that new column.
This is like @krassowski's answer,
but it doesn't require you to know the names of df's indices in advance.

```py
df.stack().rename_axis([*df.index.names, "var_name"]).rename("value")
```

Comment: It can be done with the mapper from my answer (`index={None: 'var_name'}`) too which does not require referencing the `df` second time.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a phantom column name when calling `stack`, just rename the column axis beforehand:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({col: range(3) for col in list("ABC")})
df.rename_axis(columns="lol_goodbye_columns").stack()
```

```
   lol_goodbye_columns
0  A                      0
   B                      0
   C                      0
1  A                      1
   B                      1
   C                      1
2  A                      2
   B                      2
   C                      2
dtype: int64
```