# Group by a dataframe in Pandas with common values across columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas for example:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    B    10/10/2016
B    A    09/12/2016
A    C    08/11/2016
```

I would like for each unique entry in Col1 and Col2 to get their Col3 values. The problem is that a user can either be in Col1 or Col2, so a groupby Col1 will miss the B - A line.

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

```
df.set_index(['Col3']).stack().reset_index(-1, drop=True)
```

to get:

```
Col3
10/10/2016    A
10/10/2016    B
09/12/2016    B
09/12/2016    A
08/11/2016    A
08/11/2016    C
```

which you could further process, for instance using (assuming the above was assigned to `result`:

```
result.groupby(result.values).apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())

A    [10/10/2016, 09/12/2016, 08/11/2016]
B                [10/10/2016, 09/12/2016]
C                            [08/11/2016]
```

Alternatively, you could use `pd.melt`:

```
pd.melt(df, value_vars=['Col1', 'Col2'], id_vars='Col3')

         Col3 variable value
0  10/10/2016     Col1     A
1  09/12/2016     Col1     B
2  08/11/2016     Col1     A
3  10/10/2016     Col2     B
4  09/12/2016     Col2     A
5  08/11/2016     Col2     C
```

See also:

```
df.set_index(['Col3']).stack().reset_index()

         Col3 level_1  0
0  10/10/2016    Col1  A
1  10/10/2016    Col2  B
2  09/12/2016    Col1  B
3  09/12/2016    Col2  A
4  08/11/2016    Col1  A
5  08/11/2016    Col2  C
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your swift response. How I can now group by the second column that was created, since there is no heading for it?

Comment: You can use `groupby(level=1)`, accepts both `integer` and `label`.

Comment: Is there a way to store your first command into a dataframe? I tried to user pd.Series( ), but again I cannot pass a name to the result.values so that I can massage them easier..

Comment: See update - let me know if that's not what you were looking for.

Comment: Many thanks. I found how to name the column after stack here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998893/set-column-names-when-stacking-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Added a `pd.melt()` example. If you change `.reset_index(-1, drop=True)` to just `.reset_index()`, you also get column names. You can then use `.rename()`.