# How do I stack a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my initial data:

```
name  s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
a     sd fg fd wer er
b     df rf qw NaN NaN
```

This should be my output:

```
name  s
a     sd 
a     fg 
a     fd 
a     wer 
a     er
b     df 
b     rf 
b     qw 
b     NaN 
b     NaN
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is `final result` what you want the data to look like? Also, it's good etiquette to show what you've tried so far on your own before just posting your problem and asking for someone to solve it.

Comment: Yes Finaldata is the result i want

Comment: Well then transposition is not the right term for this. I don't see any pattern in your desired result and the initial data.

Comment: Your Final data is not the transposed form of Initial data.

Comment: Also, if you're convinced that you do indeed want a transposition, then check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html A simply google search before posting here saves everyone a lot of trouble.

Comment: Just df.melt('name')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937491/matrix-transpose-in-python)

Comment: @LxL if you check the problem in body this problem is not a matrix transpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to get a dataframe which looks like that, you should try to use

```
dataframe_name.stack()
```

Comment: +1 more details of this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998893/set-column-names-when-stacking-pandas-dataframe)